Keyboard shortcut for sleep
Now that the keyboards have Touch ID sensors instead of Power/Eject keys, the sleep keyboard shortcut no longer works.
Are there any workarounds how to put a Mac to sleep using only the keyboard?

You can still buy keyboards with a media eject key, so it's clear Apple has decided that you only get a key shortcut to sleep your Mac is you have a physical media eject key different than a Touch ID key.

https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts-mac/intro-to-shortcuts-apdf22b0444c/mac

I've not seen any workaround to change that, but you can add a sleep shortcut and assign any keyboard shortcut you desire (except for power button).

Here I chose the closest key I find convenient to option + command + power which is option + command + delete.
You can add it to the menu bar, add it to the dock, trigger the shortcut from Siri or watch or other ways, too instead of needing to press keys (which you can still do).
You don't have to use shortcuts app if the benefits above aren't needed - the keyboard settings in the System Preferences app allows the sleep action to be assigned there to any shortcut you care to define. For any of these, restart the OS to be sure the assignment you have works in all apps.

Does it work for you, when you quit Shortcut app? Because somehow it only works for me when I'm running the app and stops when I quit it..?

Alright, it works, I had to restart the computer. Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!
